# A better way to swap form field type depending on context

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to make a single form type to handle both of the below scenarios?

I'm working on an application where a "normal" user (e.g. ROLE_USER) can perform a task by filling out a form. When the record gets created, he is linked to the event table. Additionally the ROLE_ADMIN user can link people on their behalf (using the same form with an additional 'user' field), selecting the user from a list of users.

At the moment I have an "eventType" and an "eventAdminType" with 98% code duplication. I've read about transformers and also form events, but I'm not entirely sure how I can adapt them to my needs.

Form code of "eventType":

```
$builder
    ->add(
        'reservedSlots', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5'),
            'required'  => true,
        )
    )
```

Form code of "eventAdminType":

```
$builder
    ->add('user')
    ->add(
        'reservedSlots', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5'),
            'required'  => true,
        )
    )
```

Entity code:

```
class EventUser
{
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @var type
 */
private $user;
...
// all the other fields
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $reservedSlots
```

How would I create a single form type the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create form type classes for both of your types and have one extend another:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class EventAdminType extends EventType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // fields for the admin form
    }
}
```

Here's some additional info about [creating form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes).

Comment: I like it. Sometimes the answer is so simple! Thanks gilden